# Application of Baire Category theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analyticity, baire-category

Suppose that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $[a,b]$ and suppose that for any $a ≤ x ≤ b$  the Taylor series of $f$ has positive radius of convergence at $x$. Use the Baire Category Theorem to show that $f$ must be analytic on a subinterval of $[a,b ]$.

Comment: Hint. For each $x$ pick $n(x)$ such that Taylor series converges in $(x-\dfrac1{n(x)},x+\dfrac1{n(x)})$. Let $A_n=\{x\in(a,b):n(x)=n\}$. Note that $(a,b)$ is the union of the $A_n$ so the closure of at least one $A_n$ must contain an interval $(c,d)$.

Comment: @Mirko:  Don't you need to use $[a,b]$ in order to have a complete/compact (sub) space to apply Baire?

Comment: Thank you Mirko. Your hint is helpful. How do we show Taylor series converges to $f$ in the interval $(c,d)$? We have to show f is analytic!

Comment: @Mathsira:: I think when the T-series of $f$ converges at x, it converges to $f(x)$

Comment: @Gary: Then we have an interval which f is analytic in before applying Baire Category according to Mirko hint !

Comment: @Mathsira: Mirko is using Baire category to conclude the existence of $(c,d)$ , where $x$ converges.

Comment: BTW: What I meant to say is that, in your problem statement, your OP, I assume when they state that the series converges, they mean it converges to $f(x)$. OF course a T-series may converge to values other than $f(x)$.

Comment: @Gary. No, when they say the Taylor series converges they must _not_ mean that it converges to $f$. Because if we're given that the series converges to $f$ on some interval then $f$ is analytic on that interval, more or less by definition.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You're right, duh! myself.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You're the heavy-duty analyst: do you know any special property of the set of points where a Taylor series for $f$  (smooth, of course)  converges  to $f(x)$? ( no pressure :) )

Comment: @Gary. I really don't have any ideas on how to do the problem, sorry. "heavy-duty analyst", I like that. Specializes in picking other people's work to shreds...

Comment: @Gary.: Note that you actually can use the Baire category theorem on the open interval $(a,b)$ - meager / nonmeager are topological properties, so you can use the theorem on any topological space which is homeomorphic to a complete metric space.  $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and with a little work you can even write down a complete metric for $(a,b)$ which induces the usual topology.

Comment: A solution is contained in *A Primer of Real Functions*, Ralph P. Boas, Harald P. Boas on page 192. See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=uQtykVwbrm4C&pg=PA192#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from the argument given in the link in my comment above. See the link for details.

Hint:

For $k$ a positive integer, define 
$$
E_k=\bigl\{ \,y\in [a,b]\,\mid \, \sup_n |f^{(n)} (y)/ n!|^{1/n}<   k\,\bigr\}.
$$

For a given $y$, the quantity $\sup_n |f^{(n)} (y)/ n!|^{1/n}$ is finite, since the Taylor series about  $y$ has positive radius of convergence.
Use Baire to show some $E_k$ is not nowhere dense.

From the  subinterval obtained via the appeal to Baire, argue that the Lagrange form of the Taylor remainder at a $y$ in this subinterval tends to $0$ for every $x$ sufficiently close   to $y$.